# "An actual answer to the question" or "the actual answer to the question"?

Tags: articles, definite-article, indefinite-article

Tell me please which article I have to use in the following context: the indefinite or definite article.

> Why didn't you go to school yesterday? I want to know **an**/**the** actual answer.

I have heard native English speakers use **an** in similar contexts. Do native English speakers use *an* in similar cotexts because *answer* is somehow modified   by *actual*?

Comment: To give ***an*** answer implies there could be other possible responses. If you give ***the*** answer, this implies there are no other answers (more specifically, that only ***the*** answer as given is "factually correct"). In your context, the word ***actual*** is syntactically and semantically irrelevant (except as a kind of "intensifier", which arguably emphasises that the speaker wants the *true* answer, but that's pragmatically obvious anyway). Also note that idiomatically most native speakers would say *I want [to know] **the truth*** here.

Comment: (certainly not ***...a truth***)

Comment: Let's say I gave someone a math problem to solve and if I say to then "I want an anwer to it in five minutes" that would mean that I want any answer, not necessarily the right one. But If I say "I want the answer" that would mean I want the correct answer. Am I right?

Comment: Not really. Native speakers simply wouldn't think like that. Pragmatically, it should be obvious you're not looking for "incorrect" answers, so *in practice* we wouldn't normally be consciously aware of the "any answer / the *correct* answer" distinction when making the arbitrary stylistic choice between definite and indefinite article in such contexts. That distinction is just something you *could* bear in mind in certain contexts - but it's not normally relevant, so don't "over-analyse" it.

Comment: I got it, but what should I say in my example "I want an answer" or "I want the answer"?

Comment: Use whichever you like - no-one's likely to interpret your intended meaning differently dependent on the choice you make. And to further complicate matters, note that it's quite possible to say *I want **my** answer before you leave* rather than *I want **your** answer...* That's to say, an "answer" is a slippery concept, which might "belong" to either the asker or the responder, and which might or might not be "unique" in any given context.

Comment: (Ah - if I remember, you're *Russian*, and Russian doesn't actually *have* articles. Just one extra problem for you to get your head around! :)

Comment: Rather a speaker of Russian. It doesn't matter though

Answer (score 2):

*An* actual answer is a reply that answer the question instead of going around it. *The* actual answer is the correct reply.

Let's say a politician was bribed. I ask him "were you bribed?". If he says "my finances are none of your concern", that is not an answer to the question. If he says "No", that is *an* actual answer to the question, but a wrong one (a lie). If he says "Yes", that is *the* actual answer to the question (the truth).